# Pandas: Sum of column produces unexpected negative values or NaT when used on GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which contains run-data of testcases.
The most important metric in that dataframe is the column 'Elapsed Time', which is a timedelta object that tells the run time of a specific testcase.

The dataset looks like this: *(nothing is sorted, even if it might seem so btw)*

|  | Test key | Started At | Finished At | Elapsed Time | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | TEST-1676 | 2021-06-10 14:40:00 | 2021-06-10 15:24:00 | 0 days 00:44:00 | 8.0.1.0 |
| 1 | TEST-1518 | 2021-06-11 12:14:00 | 2021-06-11 12:36:00 | 0 days 00:22:00 | 8.0.1.0 |
| 2 | TEST-1518 | 2021-06-11 09:29:00 | 2021-06-11 09:44:00 | 0 days 00:15:00 | 8.0.1.0 |

...

|  | Test key | Started At | Finished At | Elapsed Time | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1037 | TEST-1140 | 2018-11-28 09:35:00 | 2018-11-28 10:35:00 | 0 days 01:00:00 | nan |
| 1038 | TEST-1138 | 2018-11-28 10:56:00 | 2018-11-28 11:08:00 | 0 days 00:12:00 | nan |

[RAW DATA in CSV format](https://pastebin.com/Ekh2FjfZ)

When I attempted to group this data by Version

```py
run_groups = df_runs.groupby(['Version'])
```

I noticed that the sum of the timedelta is not correct when applied to all groups:

```py
# Grouping dataframe
run_groups = mockup.groupby(['Version'], dropna=False)
# Sum on each individual group == sum on seperate dataframes
print(run_groups.get_group('7.1.0.0')['Elapsed Time'].sum())
print(run_groups.get_group('7.2.0.0')['Elapsed Time'].sum())
print(run_groups.get_group('8.0.0.0')['Elapsed Time'].sum())
print(run_groups.get_group('8.0.1.0')['Elapsed Time'].sum())
# Sum on the groupByDataframe
run_groups['Elapsed Time'].sum()
```

Output:

[image: output]

- What am I doing wrong?
- Why is the sum different when applied to all groups?
- How come that I get a negative timedelta when summerizing?

**Edit:**

Here is the code, which produces the faulty output for me:

https://pastebin.com/50qPnnA0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing mozways answer and some more comments, it seems he didn't have problems with the data.

I then checked my data for NaN values using:

```py
df_na = df_runs[df_runs.isna().any(axis=1)]
df_na
```

which returned several rows which didn't have any dates filled in.

That's a failure in the data given, there shouldn't be ANY NaN values in the date columns, because a test-run cannot finish without those values.

However this shouldn't matter for the `sum()` function, since `NaN` values are simply ignored. This is shown by using `sum` on the individual groups, where it works.

**Why does this produce faulty values on my machine?** - I don't know.

**How did I fix it?**

Either by dropping the `NaN` values or replacing them with zero's.

```py
# EITHER: drop NaN values
df_runs = df_runs.dropna()
# OR: replace NaN with Timedelta zero
df_runs['Elapsed Time'] = df_runs['Elapsed Time'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 8 rows with NaNs as Version. By defaults, groupby drops the NaNs, thus the missing 6h 50min.

Use:

```
df_runs.groupby(['Version'], dropna=False)['Elapsed Time'].sum()
```

output:

```
Version
7.1.0.0   136 days 15:27:00
7.2.0.0    17 days 15:23:00
8.0.0.0     4 days 05:17:00
8.0.1.0     0 days 06:09:00
NaN         0 days 06:50:00
Name: Elapsed Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I still get the weird data, even when using `dropna=False`. It's not about missing 6h 50min, it's about getting `-106616 days +15:39:43.145224192` or `NaT` as a result, even though it's just running sum()

Comment: I didn't get that with your data

Comment: Ok that's weird then. I'm working inside jupyter, so let me import freshly from the CSV

Comment: Here is my code producing the problem, using my raw-data csv from the question: https://pastebin.com/raw/50qPnnA0 (the output is the same as above in the question)

Comment: @HackXIt which pandas version do you use? I ran your code and didn't get an issue, all positive deltas

Comment: pandas 1.3.2, numpy 1.21.2 and python 3.8.3

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say, but to me the problem is not reproducible…

Comment: I reproduced this in a virtualenv too... that's so weird. Can I debug this somehow?

Comment: When using `run_groups['Elapsed Time'].apply(lambda x: x.sum())` it returns the expected result, because then it's summerizing on each group individually... But whyyy??

Comment: When using `dropna()` on the dataframe before doing anything, I get the correct results.

Comment: Do you know why `NaN` values could procude this error? I noticed there are missing dates in the *.csv, which shouldn't be there in the first place. But from my understanding, `sum()` would ignore `NaN` values? Maybe this behaves differently on groupByDataframes?

Comment: I have seen those but they will indeed be ignored by sum. I have honestly no clue what your issue is, all is fine by me…

Comment: Alright... Well.. I'll just drop those NaN values and ignore this weird result for now. Maybe someone else knows or can reproduce it.